# Mongoid - One way references

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to do a one way reference in mongoid?

I would like to do something like:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :blogs, :class_name => "Blog", :inverse_of => :editor
  has_one :active_blog, :class_name => "Blog", :inverse_of => :active_users
end
```

and the blog model:

```
class Blog
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => "User", :inverse_of => :blogs

end
```

So, basically, I would like the User to store an object id referencing the blog that it is currently editing/posting to.  I do not need the blog to know about the active users, only the other way around.

It seems like the canonical way to do this would be to use 'belongs_to' on the User, and 'has_many' on the Blog.  This does work, but it isn't ideal because it doesn't really semantically express the relationship between the two models.

I am new to Mongoid, and have not been able to find a better answer.  Is there a better way to set up this type of releationship?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not even want to create even the accessor `active_user` on blog side, you can have:

```
class User
  belongs_to :active_blog, :class_name => "Blog", :inverse_of => nil
end
```

On the other hand has_many/has_one and belongs_to seems perfectly fine to me. It would not store user_ids in blog and blog doesn't need to know about active user unless you decide it should and start using the accessor from blog side.

Comment: Thanks, this still doesen't really express the relationship between the models like I would like (A User isn't really meant to "belong to" the Blog), but I guess I can't always expect my code to read like english.

Comment: you can replace `belongs_to` with `referenced_in` if you like the sound of it better :)

Comment: Woot!  This just saved me a lot of pain!